# Nonparametric repeated measures: all versus control test

Tags: nonparametric

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gI0xQcLIplA

In the video link I have attached, a particular Friedman's test is implemented for a comparison of several treatments against a control. I am not sure if this implementation is well known. My knowledge is that Friedman compares several treatments in an all-to-all fashion. Also, I do not know if this tests maintains the Type I error constant.

This proposed test would be a non-parametric version of a Dunnett's test, with repeated measures.

Particularly, I wanted to know:

- Are there open source references about this test? the video has a website reference (http://appliednonparametricstatistic.blogspot.com), and there is a cited book there called "Applied Nonparametric Statistics" by Wayne A. Daniel [http://www.amazon.com/Applied-Nonparametric-Statistics-Wayne-Daniel/dp/0534381944](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0534381944). I guess that more explanations about publications could be there. Any guiding content with more references would be useful.
- Is the Type I error controlled by using this test on a comparison of a higher number of treatments against a control?

Regards,
Ignacio

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found theoretical discussion of the test in the following book (section 7.4).

[http://www.amazon.com/Nonparametric-Statistical-Methods-Myles-Hollander/dp/0471190454](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471190454)

and this publication for extended tables.
http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610917708812033

It is known as the multiple comparisons (Nemenyi, Wilcoxon-Wilcox, Miller) k - 1 treatments versus control test.